# I have experience in Different Fields, but can't find a job. Am I employable?

Tags: job-search, retail

I have recently begun to really think about what direction to go in. I have also recently lost a job, due to no fault of my own. I have career goals, and I am not sure what direction to take. I have started to look for work again, but now it's that I just need a job. I can't seem to find one and starting to wonder if I am unemployable.

I have experience in at least 3 fields, the main ones being hospitality/food service, retail, and healthcare and am focusing my job search on those. I also have managerial experience in retail and healthcare. At this same time I am looking for work, I am also pursuing two master's degrees.

I feel that all my experience in these very different fields would be an asset and give me a unique skill set. However, I feel I am all over the place and I have the resume for every job that I apply for that combines the jobs I have had in those industries.

Could all my experience actually be a hindrance as opposed to an asset? How come I can't get a job?

Comment: Hello there welcome to The Workplace :). Please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to start to learn your ways on this site, and know what topics are ok and accepted. When you read the help center you will see that your question lacks a Goal that we can help you with (there is no goal/point in saying "yes/no you are/arent employable")... perhaps you care to rephrase your post into something we can help you with

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague. There is no way for us to know an answer to your question. You don't tell us what job you want. You don't tell us what jobs you get rejected from, what is on your CV or how you think you can fit a job with not one, but *two* masters degrees at the same time. Please ask a more detailed question, so you can get an answer focused on your actual problem, instead of well meant guesses what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel that all my experience in these very different fields would be
> an asset and give me a unique skill set.

Uniqueness doesn't necessarily add value.

If you are applying to be a food server, virtually no employer would care that you had once been a trapeze artist. If you are applying to be a software engineer, your two years of experience making tofu ice cream are unlikely to matter.

> Could all my experience actually be a hindrance as opposed to an
> asset?

Relevant experience won't be a hindrance. Irrelevant experience may be a hindrance if it makes you look like you have no idea what you want to do for work.

> How come I can't get a job?

Certainly you understand that nobody here can know why you can't get a job. Perhaps you have a good friend or someone in your professional network who would give you honest feedback.

Lots of things could be preventing you from landing a job

- Your resume might be poor
- Your interviewing skills might be poor
- You may be aiming too high in the jobs you are seeking
- You might have wide experience but no depth
- Potential employers might think your pursuit of two master's degrees means that you won't stick around in their job for long
- etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Joe's answer is good - but I'm going to give a slightly conflicting answer:

*Focus on transferable skills*

So, you've worked behind a Bar and you want to move into Sales - talk about your People skills, identifying what people want (who may not know themselves) and dealing with people who want something that they can't have.

Sometimes you might need a little bit of artistic licence on this - but with enough time and practice - you can make anything a Transferable...

"Yes, I ran a successful Multi-national business that specialized in cross-country logistics, we vertically integrated with all aspects of our supply chain to ensure that we had a seemless pipeline from production to our end Consumer"

(Member of a Drug Cartel)

Answer (score 1):

> I feel that all my experience in these very different fields would be an asset and give me a unique skill set.

Most businesses are not looking for a unique skillset. Everyone has a unique skillset.

Just keep applying and you'll find work.